# ASP.NET Converting ListBox control to DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am using VS2005 C#.

I am trying to convert my ListBox control to the use of DDL.

However in my function of adding a list of user to a specific role, it enables multiple selection in the ListBox.

I would like to change it to the use of DDL, which only allows single selection.

Below is the code:

```
    string[] newusers = new string[UsersListBox.GetSelectedIndices().Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < newusers.Length; i++)
    {
        newusers[i] = UsersListBox.Items[UsersListBox.GetSelectedIndices()[i]].Value;
    }
```

The error pointed out that `System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList' does not contain a definition for 'GetSelectedIndices`.

May I know what can I alter my code for the use of DDL instead of ListBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `DropDownList` cannot have multiple items selected, so there is not a `GetSelectedIndices()` method, as you have noticed.  Instead there is a `SelectedIndex` property.

```
string newuser = null;
if (UserListBox.SelectedIndex > -1)
{
    newuser = UsersListBox.Items[UsersListBox.SelectedIndex].Value;
}
```